# Exam project python, removing minimum value from array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Down below is my code so far (`computeFinalGrades`)
Inside the code I am using another code (`roundGrade` - this works)
I get the error code `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'remove'`
Down below you can also see the description of the assignment.

I have tried searching for any solutions in here but the ones I find does not work properly.
If any of you have any better solutions, feel free to share.

```
import numpy as np
from gradesRounded import roundGrade

def computeFinalGrades(grades):
    if -3 in grades:
        gradesFinal= -3
    elif len(grades)>=2:
        grades.remove(min(grades))
        finalgrade = np.mean(grades)
        gradesFinal = roundGrade(finalgrade)
    elif len(grades)==1:
        gradesFinal = grades
    return gradesFinal

#print((computeFinalGrades(np.array([[7,4,10],[7,4,12]])))) - this is the testcode
```

roundGrade code:

```
def roundGrade(grades):
    gradesRounded = []
    for grades in grades:
        if (-5 <grades<- 1.5):
            grade = '-3'
        elif (-1.5 <=grades< 1.5):
            grade = '00'
        elif (1.5 <=grades< 3):
            grade = '02'
        elif (3 <=grades< 5.5):
            grade = '4'
        elif (5.5 <=grades< 8.5):
            grade = '7'
        elif (8.5 <=grades< 11):
            grade = '10'
        elif (11 <=grades< 15):
            grade = '12'
        gradesRounded.append(grade)
    return gradesRounded
```

and description:

> input = grades: An N × M matrix containing grades on the 7-step-scale
> given to N students on M different assignments. output= gradesFinal: A
> vector of length n containing the final grade for each of the N
> students.
>
> For each student, the final grade must be computed in the following
> way:
>
> 1. If there is only one assignment (M = 1) the final grade is equal to the grade of that assignment.
> 2. If there are two or more assignments (M > 1) the lowest grade is discarded. The final grade is computed as the mean of M − 1 highest
>    grades rounded to the nearest grade on the scale (using the function
>    roundGrade).
> 3. Irrespective of the above, if a student has received the grade −3 in one or more assignments, the final grade must always be −3.

Comment: Please read about [ask] and how to provide a [mre]. Frankly, we don't need to care that this is part of your assignment. You should present us with the specific issue you are currently facing with the shortest code needed to recreate it

Answer (score 1):

Then `np.remove` or `ndarray.remove` functions does not exist. You should be using `np.delete` and end up with :

```
def computeFinalGrades(grades): 
    if -3 in grades: 
        gradesFinal= -3 
    elif len(grades)>=2 : 
        np.delete(grades, np.argmin(grades)) 
        finalgrade = np.mean(grades) 
        gradesFinal = roundGrade(finalgrade) 
    elif len(grades)==1: 
         gradesFinal = grades[0] # as Keredu said below 
    
    return gradesFinal
```

Where `np.argmin` returns the index of the smallest element in the numpy array.

Comment: With this solution i just get this fault instead when i try with the above listed testcode 
"'numpy.float64' object is not iterable"

Answer (score 0):

As it's said in the error, numpy hasn't remove method. You could cast from numpy array to list and then use the remove method. Based on the comments and the code you provided:

```
import numpy as np
def roundGrade(grades):
    result = []
    for grade in grades:
        if (-5 < grade < -1.5):
            grade = '-3'
        elif (-1.5 <= grade < 1.5):
            grade = '00'
        elif (1.5 <= grade < 3):
            grade = '02'
        elif (3 <= grade < 5.5):
            grade = '4'
        elif (5.5 <= grade < 8.5):
            grade = '7'
        elif (8.5 <= grade < 11):
            grade = '10'
        elif (11 <= grade < 15):
            grade = '12'
        result.append(grade)
    return result

def computeFinalGrades(array_of_grades):
    list_of_grades = array_of_grades.tolist()
    result = []
    for grades in list_of_grades:
        if -3 in grades:
            gradesFinal= -3
        elif len(grades)>=2:
            grades.remove(min(grades))
            gradeFinal = np.mean(grades)
        elif len(grades)==1:
            gradeFinal = grades[0]
        result.append(gradeFinal)
    return roundGrade(result)
```

If we call `computeFinalGrades(np.array([[7,4,10],[7,4,12]]))`, it returns: `['10', '10']`

Comment: Thank you :-)
With this solution i just get this fault instead when i try with the above listed testcode 
"'numpy.float64' object is not iterable"

Comment: Here, we aren't doing any iteration. Could you provide the code of roundGrade function?

Comment: yeah ofc

def roundGrade(grades):
    gradesRounded = [] 
    for grades in grades: 
      
        if (-5 <grades<- 1.5):
            grade = '-3'
        elif (-1.5 <=grades< 1.5):
            grade = '00'
        elif (1.5 <=grades< 3):
            grade = '02'
        elif (3 <=grades< 5.5):
            grade = '4'
        elif (5.5 <=grades< 8.5):
            grade = '7'
        elif (8.5 <=grades< 11):
            grade = '10'
        elif (11 <=grades< 15):
            grade = '12'
        gradesRounded.append(grade) 
   
    return gradesRounded

Comment: Note that in your for loop you are doing for grades in grades, do something like for grade in grades instead.

Comment: I have just updated my answer based on what I think you expect as result.

Comment: Not sure what's going on but still getting the same error. 
I've changed the line in roundGrade to "for grade in grades" and then changed "grades" to "grade", this code still works fine and are returning a list of the rounded element. 

The second code still gives med the error "'numpy.float64' object is not iterable"
For me it makes no sense that you get the right result while i am not, when i am using the code posted above :-( 

Maybe the problem lies inside the roundGrade, in your post you are not using the loop therefore it only returns one number and not a list?

Comment: Try using exactly the same code I posted.

Comment: It works with the code finalGrade
but then the second roundGrade does not return the right result when run alone 
it says The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

The testcode for this is print(roundGrade(np.array([-2.1,0.7,6.3,8.9,10.9])))
it should return a list of rounded elements too :-)
Again thank you for helping me out

Comment: roundGrade receives a float instead of a numpy array. Note that before roundGrade inside computeFinalGrades function you use np.mean, that returns a float, so if you want to run roundGrade alone, you have to pass the mean as input of this function

Comment: so the test code should not be an array? 
and can the code still take several inputs and round them individually?
sorry for all the questions but i am all new to programming.

Comment: the main function computeFinalGrades, receives an array. The function roundGrade, used inside computeFinalGrades, receives only one number. If you want to test roundGrade, you must pass a float (a real number) as input. If you want to test computeFinalGrades, you must to pass a numpy array as input. Try to run print(roundGrade(0.7)) and computeFinalGrades(np.array([[7,4,10],[7,4,12]])) as examples.

Comment: Okay makes sense. The problem is just that the assignment tells me that roundGrade should take a vector as input and the finalGrade take a matrix (like it does). 
Is it posible to manipulate the roundGrade function to take accept a vector too?

Comment: A vector with only one value or what?

Comment: yeah that too. 
The code i posted in the beginning was tested with this print(roundGrade(np.array([-2.1,0.7,6.3,8.9,10.9]))) and returned this: [-3, 0, 7, 10, 10]

Comment: It looks like the mean must be done after then. I will update my solution.

Comment: Updated, try again please.

Comment: again then the first roundGrade works but not finalGrade
again it says 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable.
looks like it is the for loop line that is tricking it to get the error

Comment: Sorry, but I must to ask you to try it again: print(roundGrade(np.array([-2.1,0.7,6.3,8.9,10.9]))) returns ['-3', '00', '7', '10', '10'] and print(computeFinalGrades(np.array([[7,4,10],[7,4,12]]))) returns ['10', '10']. Please, make sure you are using the last version I updated.

Comment: Now it's working, it may not have copied last time.

Thank you so much :-)